# access(path, flag) returns 0 even if file exists

Tags: c, file, posix

I'm trying to write a C program for copying content from a source file to a destination file. I want to check for error by checking if the file exists and if the user can read it before attempting to copy it.
I use access() from unistd.h.

Here's the context, I have a folder :

```
.
├── src.txt
├── test
└── test.c
```

test.c is my program for testing if the file exists and if I can read it.

```
int main(){
        char* path = "src.txt";
        fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", access(path, F_OK));
        fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", access(path, R_OK));
        return 0;
}
```

In this example, as src.file exists and has permissions 664, the result should be :

```
1
1
```

But the actual output is

```
0
0
```

Even if I use the absolute path instead of relative path leading to src.txt, I get the same result. What disturbs me is if I try to open the file, it works:

test.c

```
int main(){
        char* path = "src.txt";
        fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", access(path, R_OK));
        fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", access(path, F_OK));

        FILE *f = fopen(path, "r");

        if (!f) {
                fprintf(stderr, "File couldn't be opened.\n");
        } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "File successfully opened.\n");
                fclose(f);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

It gives as output :

```
0
0
File successfully opened.
```

I'm sure I'm missing something, but I can't see what it is.

Comment: Just like your code, `access` returns 0 on successful execution and a negative value for errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `access(2)` function returns `0` on success. It returns `-1` in case you don't have the requested permissions, or the file does not exist, or the path lookup failed. See the [man page](https://man-k.org/man/Linux-4.16/2/access?r=1&q=access#RETURN_VALUE). It also sets the `errno` variable to the appropriate error code. So the output of `0`, that you are seeing is correct, because you do have read permissions on the said file.

As an aside, most of the system calls return -1 on error (for example `read(2)`, `open(2)`, `write(2)` etc) and set the `errno` variable to reflect the exact error which occurred. In order to take the correct action during an error, you need to check the value of the `errno` variable.

Answer (score 3):

*In this example, as src.file exists and has permissions 664, the result should be : `1 1` ?* No It should be `0 0`, as from the [manual page of access()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/access) .

> **RETURN VALUE**
>           On  success (all requested **permissions** granted, or mode is `F_OK` and the file exists), **zero** is returned. **On error** (at
>   least  one  bit  in  mode
>          asked  for  a  permission  that is **denied**, or mode is `F_OK` and the file
>          does not exist, or some other error  occurred),  `-1`  is  returned,  and
>          `errno` is set appropriately

This

```
fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", access(path, R_OK));
```

prints `0` as `R_OK` test whether the file exists and grants read, write, and execute permissions & as you stated `src.txt` exists & its has permission `0664`, hence it prints `0`. And this

```
 fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", access(path, F_OK));
```

also prints `0` as `F_OK` tests for the existence of the file & its true in your case, hence prints `0`.